# combine several commits on one if it's commits pushed on repository

Tags: git

I opened pull request and I had several commits on it. Can I will combine several commits on one on opened pull request before my teem lead will merged on master branch.

Comment: What's your remote? Most have a *squash* option when merging PRs.

Comment: github. Without squash i can do it ?

Comment: Why do you want to not use the thing that's for the thing you want to do?

Comment: do you mean squash?

Comment: Yes. It does what you want, combining several commits to one: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits.

Comment: i can do it  before merging on master ? because squash - it is when i will mege on master

Comment: Why? What *problem* are you trying to solve? If you want to update the PR, just update the branch you made it from.

Comment: because i cannot rule for merge on master. But my team lead asked me do all pull request via one commit

Comment: Then why don't you ask your team lead why they don't just  squash it on the merge? Or, if they don't know how to do that, how you can do what they're asking you to

Answer (score 0):

While on your PR branch locally:

1. Squash the last n commits (replacing n with a number)

   ```
   git reset --soft HEAD~n
   git commit
   ```

   [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)
2. Push this back to your branch, which will require force since history is rewritten.

   ```
   git push --force-with-lease
   ```